# Write different type of Json Resposne into CSV format by use Python Script

Tags: python

I have different Json Response like below sample :

In My case keys is in form of column Name and data is in rows Node.

```
{
    "count": 2,
    "name": "Report",
    "columnNames": [
        "Name",
        "Address",
        "Account",            
        "Completed"       
    ],
    "rows": [
        [
            "'ABC'",
            Xyz,
             "'Admin'",
            "'Yes'"

        ],
         [
            "'ABC1'",
            Xyz,
             "'Admin'",
            "'Yes'"

        ],
 [
            "'ABC2'",
            Xyz,
             "'Admin'",
            "'Yes'"

        ]
]
}
```

and then i want to convert these json into csv format like this

```
 Name,Address,Account, Completed
 "'ABC'",Xyz,"'Admin'","'Yes'"
 "'ABC1'",Xyz,"'Admin'","'Yes'"
 "'ABC2'",Xyz,"'Admin'","'Yes'"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the csv module and some formatting, say you have a `json` object

```
import csv

csv_arr = [json["columnNames"]]

for row in json["rows"]:
   row_csv_arr = []
   csv_arr.append(row)
```

Finally, you can write to a file

```
with open("output.csv",'wb') as csv_file:
    wr = csv.writer(csv_file)
    wr.writerows(csv_arr)
```

Or get it as a string

```
# Join the arrays
for i, val in enumerate(csv_arr):
    csv_arr[i] = ", ".join(val)

csv_string = "\n".join(csv_arr)
```